# Swift: Using Preprocessor Macros

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, c-preprocessor

I've created a .swift file that's mixed in with an Obj-C codebase and am wondering what the best way to set constants that are dependent on preprocessed flags for specific targets.  Here's how I set constants for each target:

**For "Target A", Under "Build Settings" -> "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" -> Expand "Other Swift Flags" to reveal the following**

> Debug:  -DDEBUG -DTARGET_A
>
> Release: - DPRODUCTION -DTARGET_A

**For "Target B", Under "Build Settings" -> "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" -> Expand "Other Swift Flags"**

> Debug:  -DDEBUG -DTARGET_B
>
> Release: - DPRODUCTION -DTARGET_B

**NotificationsHub.swift**

```
#if TARGET_A
    #if PRODUCTION
        let HUBNAME = "hub1"
        let HUBLISTENACCESS = "Endpoint=endpoint1"
    #elseif DEBUG
        let HUBNAME = "hub2"
        let HUBLISTENACCESS = "Endpoint=endpoint2"
    #endif
#elseif TARGET_B
    #if PRODUCTION
        let HUBNAME = "hub3"
        let HUBLISTENACCESS = "Endpoint=endpoint3"
    #elseif DEBUG
        let HUBNAME = "hub4"
        let HUBLISTENACCESS = "Endpoint=endpoint4"
    #endif
#endif

class NotificationsHub: NSObject
{
    ...
    let hubName = HUBNAME
    let hubListenAccess = HUBLISTENACCESS
    ...
}
```

I don't like the ginormous nested if statement that precedes the class definition nor do I like setting constants outside of the class (are these global constants???) and would prefer to be able to specify each hubName and hubListenAccess in the project settings somewhere.  In Obj-C, it's possible to specify values under "Build Settings" -> "Apple LLVM 7.0 Preprocessing" -> Expand "Preprocessor Macros", but don't know how I can do this in Swift.

Comment: Did you think about using plists files?

Comment: I've looked at the .plist file for each target but didn't notice where I can specify constants. Plus, the endpoint that I'm specifying have secure access key info so plist files may not be secure enough to store those constants.

Comment: It seems like your implemented solution is the best we can do right now.

Answer (score 2):

With XCode 8 we could use the Active Compilation Conditions to add the MACRO without the -D prefix